# How to create a shortcut to run my application from start menu?

Tags: nsis

I have written nsis script.Using NSIS, how do I create StartMenu shortcut to run my application through this shortcut folder in Windows?. 
Following code working fine for opening folder using shortcut folder in STARTMENU.

```
CreateShortcut "$smprograms\my app\my shortcut.lnk" "c:\path\to\folder"
```

My question is,

Is there any way to run my application directly through this shortcut folder in STARTMENU?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extract of an installer that creates both start and uninstall (if you generate the uninstaller while installing your program) shortcuts :

```
CreateDirectory '$SMPROGRAMS\${Company}\${AppName}'
CreateShortCut '$SMPROGRAMS\${Company}\${AppName}\${AppName}.lnk' '$INSTDIR\${AppExeName}' "" '$INSTDIR\${AppExeName}' 0
CreateShortCut '$SMPROGRAMS\${Company}\${AppName}\Uninstall ${AppName}.lnk' '$INSTDIR\${AppUninstaller}' "" '$INSTDIR\${AppUninstaller}' 0
```

The `Company`, `AppName`, `AppExeName` and `AppUninstaller` are defined once somewhere else in the script, so that some portions of the script are generic enough to be reused in several installers.

Comment: what is AppExeName? setup.exe file will be generated after compiling the scirpt.Then how can i use that one? If understand correctly mean you told based exe file only to run the application? am i rite?

Comment: `AppExeName` is just a constant that is defined in the script, you can just use `CreateShortcut "$smprograms\my app\my shortcut.lnk" "c:\path\to\application.exe" "" "c:\path\to\application.exe" 0` it will create a shortcut to the application executable.

Comment: which exe file i need to specify this application.exe?. i have defined only one exe file in my script.ie setup.exe file only.This file generated after compiling the script.How can i use this?

Comment: specify the .exe of you application, or if it is not a .exe, put the .bat start the application. If it is not a .exe, the path to the icon will not work like in my example.